# A command to properly restart Plank?

Tags: plank

What is the command to restart Plank dock in case that is needed?

I have killed it with `killall plank` but now I cannot start it without logging out.

Doing `plank` in Terminal keeps it open only until the Terminal is closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know why, but `plank &` does not work for me.

What I find effective is `nohup plank &`

[Documentation on nohup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)

Comment: yes indeed. and to restart : `killall plank && nohup plank &` -- quite an abracadabra :)

Comment: I'm just curious, does the command provided by Cassidy work for someone? I see 5 upvotes, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: there must be 5 happy cases... or not: I also had up-voted it initially :)

Comment: @saintjules it' working for me, you just need to press enter after pasting `plank &` and you can close your terminal after that.

Comment: @BilalElmoussaoui yeah, I figured I had to press enter :) sorry, it's not working here, plank closes as the terminal is closed.

Answer (score 9):

The dock *should* restart itself automatically. However, if you need to manually run it from the Terminal and want it to continue running in the background, use the command `plank &`.

The `&` tells the Terminal to run the `plank` command in the background, allowing you to close the Terminal without killing the dock.

Comment: Should it be back by itself after `killall plank`? Well, after killing it the same way, `plank &` is no different than `plank` : the dock goes down with the terminal. I have to log out and in to restore the dock

Comment: does that work for you?